# IOS Bluetooth Low Energy Generic Access Profile

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, gatt

I'm working on a iOS bluetooth LE app. The app scans for peripherals and read/write with LE.
I was searching for tutorials/examples about GATT and GAP (Generic Access Profile). I wasn't able to find any beginners materials.

I hope there any one can answer my questions:

1. What is the best way to access these services (GATT & GAP)?
2. Is there any way to write/read there characteristic values (Like
   changing the device name)?
3. Is there any differences about this in IOS7 and IOS6?
4. Any more advise/help please?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got solution for this ?

Comment: It's all in the Core Bluetooth framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html